# cross image to close the light box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-lists

i have a cube when u click the cube a light box opens up.....
right now i need to to click outside to close the cube....
i am planning to implement a cross icon to close the cube....
can u tell me how to include the cross icon to close the cube......
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/wWaKs/1/

```
 $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                location.reload();

                Gallery.setOptions({
                    size: 78,
                    lightbox: false,
                    //animation:  'drop'
                    //speed:      500,
                    //closeOnEsc: true,
                    //slideshow:  false,
                    //slideshow_speed: 3000,
                    //cube_speed: 1000
                });

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you would like to use a 'close button', like the 'X' graphic in the examples above, specify its location at the top of the lightbox.js file.

```
var closeButton = 'close.gif';
```

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/